# React-native Android geolocation

Tags: android, geolocation, react-native

I need to detect user's geolocation on React-native Android but the current implementation supports only iOS. I haven't found any tutorials or related questions anywhere.

I have tried to create my own Android native component for this. I have tried it with the emulator (setting some coordinates via commandline) and with a phone but there is no gps icon in the action bar and the react callback has no data in it.

I'm trying to get the last known location immediately and I'm also setting up an event listener for updates.

```
public class GeoLocation extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

protected static final String TAG = "GeoLocation";
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
protected Location mLastLocation;


public GeoLocation(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
    buildGoogleApiClient();
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "GeoLocation";
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getReactApplicationContext())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    //WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();

    //Can I use ConcurrentHashMap instead of WritableMap?
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> params = new ConcurrentHashMap();
    params.put("lastLocation", mLastLocation.toString());
    sendEvent(getReactApplicationContext(), "geoCoordsChanged", params);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + result.getErrorCode());
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@ReactMethod
public void getLastLocation(Callback success,Callback err){
    try {
        String msg = "No location found yet";

        if(mLastLocation != null){
            msg = mLastLocation.toString();
        }

        success.invoke(msg);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        err.invoke(e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void sendEvent(ReactContext reactContext,
                       String eventName,
                       @Nullable ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> params) {
  try {
      reactContext
          .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
          .emit(eventName, params);
  } catch(Exception e){

  }
}
```

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<application
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I haven't found anything relevant from the logcat logs either. Any tips what is wrong with this code or any kind of solution for getting geocoordinates would be great!

Answer (score 8):

***UPDATE***: Sigh. I spoke to soon. It's part of 0.15.0:  https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.15.0

The official module appears not yet open-sourced (See: [Known Issues](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/known-issues.html#missing-modules-and-native-views)), but the fact that there's [documentation for using it with Android](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html#android) suggests it'll show up sometime… soon? In the mean time, here's what I have a month later and after a bit of googling:

- [rn-geolocation](https://github.com/Tiagojdferreira/rn-geolocation) (Looks straightforward. Going to give this a try.)
- [react-native-android-geolocation](https://github.com/garysye/react-native-android-geolocation) (Also looks good?)
- [react-native-background-geolocation](http://shop.transistorsoft.com/pages/react-native-background-geolocation) (Non-free for Android but looks like the real deal for serious GPS-intensive apps like running/navigation stuff)
- [react-native-geolocation-android](https://github.com/lxsameer/react-native-geolocation-android) (LGPL.)

Comment: Is it supposed to work on Android yet?  I can get maps working but not navigator.geolocation.watchPosition

Comment: [This code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blame/235b16d93287061a09c4624e612b5dc4f960ce47/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/location/LocationModule.java#L41-L46) (dated Nov. 18) seems to emit the event watchPosition listens for, so I'd venture to say yes, it should work. We had some trouble with geolocation. I'm not sure about watchPosition, but the fact that our test phone wasn't activated seems to have caused problems with high accuracy mode. I'd recommend trying the emulator and a real phone or two for a start. And of course check `adb logcat` for errors.

Comment: What do you mean 'activated'?  That could easily be the problem.  I've stepped though the java LocaltionManger in the debugger and noticed that the last know position was over 12 hours ago.  It clearly has a GPS position because I can see the blue dot on the map, it's just not being updated for some reason.

Comment: Sorry. I mean we were testing with an old phone that's no longer subscribed to Verizon service. I saw suggestions online that since geolocation uses a combination of GPS and cell towers, this may cause highaccuracy to fail. Just speculation though. RN Android also had a [bug that caused geolocation to hang forever instead of timing out](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/6376), but that's been fixed in more recent versions. We're currently using Android Studio 2's emulator which allows you to explicitly send a GPS position. Bottom line: probably should work; try multiple devices. :)