# Follow user location on React Native AirBnb's MapView [Android]

Tags: android, google-maps, reactjs, react-native, geolocation

I'm using [airbnb's map](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps) for react-native on my app. This question is for the android app since I didn't get around the iOS app yet.

**My problem:**

[navigator.geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/geolocation) works fine on emulator, but takes too long on real devices, to the point it sometimes times out on older devices.

**What I've noticed:**

if `showsUserLocation` prop is set to true, I can see the native "current position" marker on the map way before [getCurrentPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) resolves.

**What I want:**

1. I want my region to always be centered on the user's location.
2. I want either a way to access native geolocation api (should be
   faster?), or maybe someone to tell me what I'm doing wrong. Below is
   a code sample.
3. I want to still be able to detect the user's location even after the location services have been toggled on/off. This is the behaviour of the `showsUserLocation` prop, but it seems once watchPostion errors, it stops completely.

Here's what I have so far, it's very simple as it is:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        console.log("getCurrentPosition Success");
        this.setState({
          region: {
            ...this.state.region,
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          }
        });
        this.props.resetNotifications();
        this.watchPosition();
      },
      (error) => {
        this.props.displayError("Error dectecting your location");
        alert(JSON.stringify(error))
      },
      {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
    );
  }

  watchPosition() {
    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
      (position) => {
        console.log("watchPosition Success");
        if(this.props.followUser){
          this.map.animateToRegion(this.newRegion(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        this.props.displayError("Error dectecting your location");
      },
      {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
    );
  }
```

Comment: You should go out of your office or home with your devices for your location testing. Must be `enableHighAccuracy: true` in real devices. It work for me perfect.

Comment: check it this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/38125402/2955679

Comment: @pedropeixoto I did exactly all what have asked in the installation guide but showsUserLocation doesn't work for me. Can you help me out.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have always found `watchPosition` iffy between different browsers, one thing that worked for me before is to replace with `getCurrentPosition` inside a `setInterval` so that it will get the location every few seconds, and if it fails once it will retry next interval, unlike `watchPosition` which stops watching if an error occurs.

Generally browser geolocation is not very reliable, you can check this thread for some issues https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7495

Another alternative which will definitely be faster and maybe more reliable is to use the native geolocation API. Check this question for libraries that expose native geolocation for react native [React-native Android geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33341760/react-native-android-geolocation)

Comment: There's a lot to digest on the links you sent, but it will keep me going forward for sure. The bounty is about to end so I'll award it you. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. The bottom line is to use a native geolocation plugin for more reliability. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve your issue but try this:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  (position) => {
    console.log("getCurrentPosition Success");
    this.setState({
      region: {
        ...this.state.region,
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
      }
    }, () => {
      this.props.resetNotifications();
      this.watchPosition();
    });
  },
```